# Using Entity Framework Efficiently

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity framework in my ASP.NET MVC project. I need to know that if I'm dealing correctly with the following scenario.

Lets say my Employee table has over 100000 records and I have to apply various filtering according to the client requirement.

So I write 1 method ReadAll() to retrieve all the records from the database and then apply filtering to the datasource using lambda expressions.

Ex: Get employee by ID

```
public List<Employee> ReadAll()
{
   // return List<Employee>
} 


private Employee(int id)
{
   Employee obj=ReadAll().where(o=>o.empID == id).First();
}
```

I'm trying to use one read all method because there are various filtering to be applied and I do not have to write separate database access methods to each of them.

Will this affect my application performance adversely?

Comment: Ofcourse yes, you should use IQueryable instead of List

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change ReadAll to return IQueryable so that it won't execute the query until after you've applied your filter and called First() or ToList().

```
public IQueryable<Employee> ReadAll()
{
   // return List<Employee>
}
```

Entity Framework uses a concept called [deferred execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx). I encourage you to read up on it.